# How can I remove a particular list entry from a list

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
DeleteStudent(BuildContext context) {
if (stuEnroll.isEmpty || stuName.isEmpty) {
  const snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text(
      'Please enter all fields',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Color(0xffF36501)),
    ),
  );

  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
} else {
  print('Name=== $stuName');
  print('Enroll==== $stuEnroll');

  // DatabaseReference postListRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Students");
  // Future<void> newPostRef = postListRef.remove();
  final recentPostsRef =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('Students/').equalTo(stuEnroll);
  print('RECENT POST REF === $recentPostsRef');
  recentPostsRef.remove();
  // newPostRef.remove();
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => AlterStudent()),
  );
  StuNameController.text = '';

  stuEnrollController.text = '';
  setStuEnroll('');

  setStuName('');
}
}
```

When I use this code, all items under the title `Students` get removed. However, I want only that particular list to get removed which has the student enrolment number equal to `stuEnroll`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can apply the filter in this code. For this you can use

```
CollectionReference noticeCollection =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Students').where('enrollmentnumber', isNotEqualTo: stuEnroll);
```

Also if you want you can apply filter in view side as if enrollmentnumber equals stuEnroll, return null else return (Whatever view you want)